# Angular-Fullstack get user_id after create it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I am creating users and need to get the id of the recently created user, but I'm not able to get it through the callback. This is what I have:

**controller.js:**

```
Auth.createUser({
        name: this.user.name,
        email: this.user.email,
        password: this.user.password,
      }, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user); // Return only the params 'name', 'email, 'password', not the '_id'
}
```

**auth.service.js:**

```
/**
     * Create a new user
     *
     * @param  {Object}   user     - user info
     * @param  {Function} callback - function(error, user)
     * @return {Promise}
     */
    createUser(user, callback) {
      return User.save(user, function(data) {
        $cookies.put('token', data.token);
        currentUser = User.get();
        return safeCb(callback)(null, user);
      }, function(err) {
        Auth.logout();
        return safeCb(callback)(err);
      })
        .$promise;
    },
```

**EDIT:**
If I try through the API end point:

```
$http.post('/api/users/', {
        name: this.usr.name,
        email: this.usr.email,
        password: this.usr.password
      })
```

I get this object:

```
Object { data: Object, status: 200, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "OK" }
```

Where:

```
data {
    token: eyJhbGciOiJ...Vs3Ng14ycQA
    __proto__: Object 
}
```

So I cannot get the user info anyway.

Could you help me, guys?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not return the user ID from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are making your task more complicated I think you have misunderstood some concept. Let me try to clear it.

> ok so whenever you have promise to return you get the option resolve
>   and reject that means when either resolve or reject gets called you
>   can get it in then...or...catch call.

```
Auth.createUser({
        name: this.user.name,
        email: this.user.email,
        password: this.user.password,
      }, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user); // Return only the params 'name', 'email, 'password', not the '_id'
}
```

**Your createUser signature should be**

> function createUser(OBJECT,CALLBACK_FUNCTION)

here callback function means that function will be called whenever you want, if you call that function then only you can call  this function -->

> function (err, user) {
>           console.log(user); // Return only the params 'name', 'email, 'password', not the '_id' }

**here you are not handling promise you are making a function call which has callback as parameter so you have to write that function like this.. and call the callback accordingly**

```
  createUser(user, callback) {
  User.save(user, function(data) {
    $cookies.put('token', data.token);
    currentUser = User.get();
    //return safeCb(callback)(null, user);
    //call that function callback with needed parameter.
    callback(null,user);//giving first para as null as no error
  }, function(err) {
    Auth.logout();
    //return safeCb(callback)(err);
    callback(err);
  })
},
```

**Hopefully this will help.**
Let me know if you still have any doubt.
 Edited

May be you missed a bracket..

```
 Auth.createUser({
         name: this.user.name,
         email: this.user.email,
         password: this.user.password,
       }, function (err, user) {
         console.log(user); // Return only the params 'name', 'email, 'password', not the '_id' 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for being so clear, but I'm using Angular-Fullstack generator and the createUser function is given by this framework, that's why I'd rather not to change it.. It's been created to make things easiar, isn't it?? But as you said, I'm missunderstanding how the function works...

Comment: ok so if you are using framework then you can not change that functions cool but then you have to understand it because they have given $promise over there then we should use then and catch to get the resolve or reject part

Comment: you will have to check their documentation then and about the safeCb as well.

Comment: Yes/ sometimes it makes things easier but according to me its always good to understand it first :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's why I was asking if someone could help me, I just don't find any docs about this... :/ Thank you anyway!!!